# How to rotate 2 images independently on html canvas

Tags: image, html, canvas, rotation

I want to show a set of gears using HTML canvas. I've got the following http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/RpmuE/ but the little cog rotates around the big cog rather than staying fixed and just rotating. Once I have it fixed I can work out the relative speeds of the cogs but I can't work out why it moves around the main cog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RpmuE/1/)**

Hah cool idea, the main thing I think causing the issue was a missing `restore`. A thing to remember is you want to do your translates before the rotations. Otherwise you will translate the `canvas`, and then rotate the whole `canvas` thus rotating everything on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok. That makes sense. Bring on the gearbox!